# .insertAfter or .append to an Element Id with Javascript. it's a script tag so it can't be with $

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a script after a div, this is what I have:

```
<div id="uno">insert after this</div><br />
<p>this is a paragraph</p><br />
<div>this is a div</div>

var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.setAttribute('src', 'Scripts/start.debug.js');
document.body.appendChild(myscript);
```

and this code will ad `<script src="Scripts/start.debug.js"></script>` at the end of the page, and i need it after div `#uno`.  What can I use instead of `document.body.appendChild`?

Comment: Why does it need to be after a particular element? The only reason to put script elements in a particular place is when they reference elements during load. Otherwise, they can go pretty much anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<script>
// This function inserts newNode after referenceNode
function insertAfter( referenceNode, newNode )
{
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore( newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling );
}
insertAfter(document.getElementById("uno"), newScript);
</script>
```

Even if a nextSibling doesn't exist in the DOM it will still work "because when the second parameter of insertBefore is null then the newNode is appended to the end of the parentNode". A great description can be found here: http://www.netlobo.com/javascript-insertafter.html.

Comment: [W3C DOM Core insertBefore](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727).

Comment: @ scrappedia, how do i target the head of the document?

right after the the apend tag, in other works <heah>myscrip. other stuff.</head>

something like firstChild.

thank you.

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

Comment: Please read the bottom answer, i can't type on the commet box for some reason...please read below thanks

Comment: @ scrappedcolo works to Head of document bottom

    var a = document.createElement('script');
    a.setAttribute('src', 'minini.js');
    document.head.appendChild(a);


Works to ID

    var myscript = document.createElement('script');
    myscript.setAttribute('src', 'minini.js');
    function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }
    insertAfter(document.getElementById("tres"), myscript);
but i couldn't make it work with your method: document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

thanks.