# How to store data if checkbox is selected

Tags: php

I'm doing this one using PHP.

I'm doing some basic quiz application and it has a backend. On my backend, I am setting up a quiz for students to answer. One of my interface is like this.

[image]

If the user checked the box, it means 1950 is the answer. How would I process that one in my database to determine that 1950 has been the answer of the question.

My Database is like this.

```
tbl_choices
Id,Choice,isAnswer
```

so ideally, it would be stored like this.

```
tbl_choices
ID         CHOICE      isAnswer
001         1900          0
002         1800          0
003         1950          1
004         1850          0
```

My question here is how would I code it in a sense when a user will check the checkbox and the textinput right beside it will have a value of `isAnswer` as `1`.

Just an additional info: When a user will click that `+` button it will add a new textinput and if user will click `-` button it will delete a textinput, but I got that all covered.

The choices are dynamic, it will changed, that above that I've shown you is just an example.

*P.S: Sorry for the title, I don't know what's the title of this kind of question :-)*

Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Comment: A question can have many answers :-)

Comment: I highly recommend a submit button along with the checkbox. If not just submit it Via ajax, onblur

Comment: is the value in the imput text field mutable? or is it set?

Comment: @EyalAlsheich Yes it is mutable. It will change depending what the user will set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try html like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1900" name="answer1[]">
<input type="text" value="1900" name="answer2[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1800" name="answer1[]">
<input type="text" value="1800" name="answer2[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1950" name="answer1[]">
<input type="text" value="1950" name="answer2[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1850" name="answer1[]">
<input type="text" value="1850" name="answer2[]" />
```

and then use php code:

```
foreach($_POST['answer2'] as $v){


    if(in_array($v, $_POST['answer1'])) {
        $s = 1;
    }else
     $s = 0;
     $sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES(null, $v, $s)";
}
```

also on click plus update values of both check box and text field

Comment: This game me an idea. so Thanks you! :)

Answer (score 1):

in general you can use checkboxes as an array when submiting information, just name the checkboxes as an array like

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1900" name="answer1[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1800" name="answer1[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1950" name="answer1[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1850" name="answer1[]">
```

then on the server side you handle `$_POST["answer1"]` as an array and cycle through the possible answers, something like this

```
if (is_array($_POST["answer1"]))
{
  foreach($_POST["answer1"] as $answer)
  {
    // insert into database here
  }

}
```

important: this will only show what a user actualy selected, if an option is not clicked then it will not be part of the array

Comment: I already know how to store checkbox value and manipulate it in the server side, the real question is how would I know what is the textinput on the right side of the checkbox?

Comment: you can change the valeu of the checkbox with javascript to reflect any changes to the value of the input fields, thats just one way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make sense to have more than one table, one for the questions with their options and then one for the answers with the fields id, choice_id. Otherwise it is going to make generating the questions a lot more difficult especially when a number of students answer the same question?

Comment: The question is not about database design :-)

Answer (score -2):

One more thing, you could add up in the answers of your question, add row and delete row based on + and - button.

The code for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#plus").click(function() {
           $('#mytable2 tbody>tr:last').clone(true).
              insertAfter('#mytable2 tbody>tr:last');
           $('#mytable2 tbody>tr:last #st').val('');
           $('#mytable2 tbody>tr:last #newst').val('');
           $('#mytable2 tbody>tr:last #plus').val('+');
           return false;
        });
     });
```

for more detail, you may refer following link:
[Add Row on Button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026422/add-row-on-button-click)